# Burninate [editable]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, burninate-request

The [editable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/editable) tag has 328 questions and no tag wiki. I don't think you can be an expert in making things "editable". This tag is used by many questions which are seemingly unrelated, involving code from [php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php) to [java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java) to [ios](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ios). Can we burn it?

**Edit:**

@Frédéric Hamidi points out `GtkEditable`, an interface for text-editing widgets. I'm not sure that this tag is for this interface, and even if it is the tag needs some serious clean up.

Comment: Maybe. [Maybe not](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkEditable.html).

Comment: content editable is for html.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What is editable? This tag says nothing about the question. The whole purpose of tags is so experts can find questions about their area of expertise easier, and I don't see how anyone can be an expert in 'editable' things.

Let it burn.

Answer (score 4):

## [Burnination Completed!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/editable?sort=newest&pageSize=50)